# Use int64 nanotimes as array dimnames in R

Tags: r, arrays, nanotime

I have some lovely nanotimes:

```
> mynames
[1] "2020-04-15T00:29:00.000000000+00:00" "2020-04-15T00:33:00.000000000+00:00"
```

Which I'd like to add as dimnames to my array:

```
> a
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA
```

However, they seem to be converted into rolled over strings:

```
> dimnames(a)[1] <- list(values=mynames)
> a
                      [,1] [,2]
1.39309697650764e-202   NA   NA
1.39315136717363e-202   NA   NA

> dimnames(a)
[[1]]
[1] "1.39309697650764e-202" "1.39315136717363e-202"
```

How can I keep my dimname assignment as nanotime/integer64s?  Or if they are forced to character to be dimnames, how can I at least keep them from being strings of incorrect numbers?

You can see for example that these fail to round-trip back to suitable times:

```
> nanotime(dimnames(a)[1][[1]][1])
Error in RcppCCTZ::parseDouble(x, fmt = format, tz = tz) : 
  Parse error on 1.39309697650764e-202
```

Comment: A reproducible example using `dput` would help to verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/dimnames) of `dimnames` states that the `value` is coerced to `character`. To do all the coercing back and from to `nanotime` which is based on `integer64`, you can first coerce your `nanotime` to `integer64` and then to `character`. Then the back coercion works:

```
library(nanotime)

mynames <- c(nanotime("2020-04-15T00:29:00.000000000+00:00"),
             nanotime("2020-04-15T00:33:00.000000000+00:00"))

a <- array(NA, dim = c(2, 2))
# nanotime -> integer64 -> charachter
dimnames(a)[1] <- list(values = as.character(as.integer64(mynames)))

# character -> integer64 -> nanotime
nanotime(as.integer64(dimnames(a)[1][[1]][1]))
[1] "2020-04-15T00:29:00.000000000+00:00"
```